# Merge 3 different type lists in one new list type

Tags: c#, linq, concatenation

Having the following models (I'm posting the interfaces for simplicity).

```
public class LengthViewModel
{
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class SlopeViewModel
{
    public int Slope { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class RatingViewModel
{
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

I then have in another ViewModel an ObservableCollection of each types.

```
public ObservableCollection<LengthViewModel> Lengths { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<SlopeViewModel> Slopes { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<RatingViewModel> Ratings { get; set; }
```

I need to transform the above lists into one list, below is the new list type that it should be created.

```
public ObservableCollection<LengthSlopeRatingViewModel> Aggregate { get; set; }

public class LengthSlopeRatingViewModel
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public int Slope { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set;}
}
```

What I've tried so far but seems to stuck how to select the properties for each transformed list.

```
var lengths = Lengths.Select(p => new LengthSlopeRatingViewModel
{
    Category = p.Category,
    Length = p.Length
});

var slopes = Slopes.Select(p => new LengthSlopeRatingViewModel
{
    Category = p.Category,
    Slope = p.Slope
});

var ratings = Ratings.Select(p => new LengthSlopeRatingViewModel
{
    Category = p.Category,
    Rating = p.Rating
});

// Concat and group them, then select new type again with the properties?
CourseRatings = lengths.Concat(slopes)
    .Concat(ratings)
    .GroupBy(p => p.Category)
    .Select(g => g.ToList())
    .As<IEnumerable<LengthSlopeRatingViewModel>>()
    .ToObservableCollection();
```

Example, if you have an instance with length, slope and rating and `Category = "Black"` and another instance with `Category = "Blue"`  I should get two instances of LengthSlopeRatingViewModel, one with `Category = "Black"` and the corresponding values of the first match and one with `Category = "Blue"`.

Comment: Shouldn't the `Select` after `GroupBy` be `SelectMany` ?

Comment: Please put a but more effort into formatting your code when asking questions - there's no need for the majority of it to be indented far off over to the right. I've edit the question this time. It sounds like what you really want here is a couple of joins, to be honest... you should also say what you want to happen if the category is only in one or two of the original collections.

Comment: I admit that it needed a little bit more work the question and I see the join now, I got stuck a little bit, thanks for the editing :-)

Comment: I wonder who is the one that down voted without a reason!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining several lists by a common criteria can be done using [join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)s.

If you want a `LengthSlopeRatingViewModel` result only when **all collections contain** one **corresponding category** item:

```
Aggregate = new ObservableCollection<LengthSlopeRatingViewModel>(
    from l in Lengths
    join s in Slopes on l.Category equals s.Category
    join r in Ratings on s.Category equals r.Category
    select new LengthSlopeRatingViewModel {
        Category = l.Category,
        Length = l.Length,
        Slope = s.Slope,
        Rating = r.Rating
    });
```

If e.g. **some** ratings **are missing** and you still want a list with default ratings:

```
Aggregate = new ObservableCollection<LengthSlopeRatingViewModel>(
    from l in Lengths
    join s in Slopes on l.Category equals s.Category
    join r in Ratings on s.Category equals r.Category into ratings
    from r in ratings.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new LengthSlopeRatingViewModel {
        Category = l.Category,
        Length = l.Length,
        Slope = s.Slope,
        Rating = r?.Rating ?? 0
    });
```

Former is equivalent to:

```
Aggregate = new ObservableCollection<LengthSlopeRatingViewModel>(
    Lengths
    .Join(Slopes, _ => _.Category, _ => _.Category,
        (l, s) => new LengthSlopeRatingViewModel
            { Category = l.Category, Length = l.Length, Slope = s.Slope })
    .Join(Ratings, _ => _.Category, _ => _.Category,
        (ls, r) => { ls.Rating = r.Rating; return ls; }));
```

These should be easily adaptable to other use-cases e.g. missing slopes (add `DefaultIfEmpty`) or missing lengths (change order of joins) unless you want a real full outer join, i.e. you **expect *any* of lengths, slopes and ratings to not contain categories present in another collection**. Then creating a list of all categories and left-outer-joining the view models works:

```
var categories =
    Lengths.Select(_ => _.Category).Concat(
    Slopes.Select(_ => _.Category)).Concat(
    Ratings.Select(_ => _.Category))
    .Distinct();

Aggregate = new ObservableCollection<LengthSlopeRatingViewModel>(
    from c in categories
    join l in Lengths  on c equals l.Category into lengths
    from l in lengths.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join s in Slopes on c equals s.Category into slopes
    from s in slopes.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join r in Ratings on c equals r.Category into ratings
    from r in ratings.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new LengthSlopeRatingViewModel
    {
        Category = c,
        Length = l?.Length ?? 0, // or any other default
        Slope = s?.Slope ?? 0,
        Rating = r?.Rating ?? 0
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer, exactly what I needed!